# IOC bug in Nancy?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nancy

We have a UnitTest project where we are trying to test our Nancy Modules. In our UnitTest project we also have a fake of our api to allow us to test some other stuff.

Now we run into an issue with Nancy during the setup. This is how we setup our browser and our test:

```
Mock<ITokenController> _mockController;
_mockController = new Mock<ITokenController>();
_browser = CreateBrowser<TokenModule>(_mockController);


protected Browser CreateBrowser<TModule>(Mock controllerMock) where TModule : INancyModule
{
    var browser = new Browser(
        configurator =>
        configurator.Module<TModule>()
            .Dependency(controllerMock.Object)
            .ResponseProcessor<JsonProcessor>()
            .RequestStartup((container, pipelines, context) => SetupUser(context)));

    return browser;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Token_Login_GET_OK()
{
    // arrange
    // act
    var response = _browser.Get(MklConstants.TokenEndpoint);

    //assert
    Assert.IsTrue(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    _mockController.Verify(controller => controller.GetToken());
}
```

This works fine by it self, however if we add a fake to the project we obviously get another implementation of the same interfaces. By looking at the container we can see this and this is when the error occures.

We get the following error:

"An item with the same key has already been added."

when trying to resolve "Nancy.Routing.RouteCache".

Here is the Exception:

```
-       InnerException  {"Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.RouteCache"}    System.Exception {Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException}

    -       InnerException  {"En post med samma nyckel har redan lagts till."}  System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
    +       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
            HResult -2147024809 int
            HelpLink    null    string
    +       InnerException  null    System.Exception
            Message "En post med samma nyckel har redan lagts till."    string
            ParamName   null    string
            Source  "mscorlib"  string
            StackTrace  "   
                vid Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
                vid Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, ResolveOptions options)
                vid Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.SingletonFactory.GetObject(Type requestedType, TinyIoCContainer container, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
                vid Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ResolveInternal(TypeRegistration registration, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)
                vid Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer.ConstructType(Type requestedType, Type implementationType, ConstructorInfo constructor, NamedParameterOverloads parameters, ResolveOptions options)" string
    +       TargetSite  {Void ThrowArgumentException(System.ExceptionResource)} System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
```

Now, our suspicion to why this happens is that Nancy picks the same implementation of the interface both times it tries to resolve and hence we run into this issue on the second resolve.

Any help in fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The exception details don't appear to include `An item with the same key has already been added`. Where there two exceptions, or just the one?

Comment: I'm Swedish so:

"En post med samma nyckel har redan lagts till."

Actually translates to :

"An item with the same key has already been added."

Only one exception but a chain of InnerExceptions. I just added the innermost and the header of the exception prior to the innermost exception.

Comment: My apologies @TOMTEFAR ! Which line throws that exception?

Comment: I'can't see what line since it is in Nancy and I have not been able to find any pdb files. You have the stack trace showing the method in nancys TinyIoc where it happens but no more.

The way we can observe it is in our own implementation of IRouteMetadataProvider. It is called 2 times since the fake exists and we get the exception when the second run is executing with the same routeDescription in GetMetadata().

Comment: -> Follow from above:

This makes us beleive that you pick the same object from TinyIoc on both runs but they are not the same object.